# FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040: java.net.BindException: Address already in use java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: spark-streaming

I am trying to deploy a spark-streaming online wordcount program on Spark cluster environment.`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class WordCountOnline {
    public  static void main(String[] args){
    SparkConf conf =new SparkConf();
   conf.setMaster("spark://SparkMaster:7077").setAppName("WordCountOnline");
    JavaSparkContext sc=new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaStreamingContext jsc=new JavaStreamingContext(conf,Durations.seconds(5));
    JavaReceiverInputDStream lines=jsc.socketTextStream("SparkMaster",9999); 
    JavaDStream<String> words=lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
    public Iterable<String> call(String line) throws Exception {
        return Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
    }
});
    JavaPairDStream<String,Integer> pairs=words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
    public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String word) throws Exception {
          return new Tuple2<String,Integer>(word,1);        
    }
});
    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordsCount=pairs.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {

    public Integer call(Integer v1, Integer v2) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return v1+v2;
    }
});
   wordsCount.print();
   jsc.start();
   jsc.awaitTermination();
   jsc.close();
}
}
```

`I am deploying on spark cluster environment.

```
$SPARK_HOME$/bin# ./spark-submit --class sparkstreaming.WordCountOnline --master spark://SparkMaster:7077 /root/Documents/WordCountOnline.jar
```

And there is a problem

```
FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040: java.net.BindException: Address already in use java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

I have checked port 4040 by

```
 netstat  -apn | grep 4040
```

The result shows port 4040 is not being listened, besides, the port I choose in my code is 9090.Why there is such kind of issue?

Comment: You need to run netstat as root to show all processes.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The problem is port 4040,why do I need to show all processes?Besides,how to show all processes?